# Correct type declarations when pushing objects created by factory to array

Tags: typescript

In typescript, if I have a factory method that may produce different objects depending on a runtime value. How can I declare that the resulting array of the created object is either one type or the other, not both?

```
interface Foo {
    fooProp: 'Foo'
}

interface Bar {
    barProp: 'Bar'
}

function barFactory(): Bar {
    return { barProp: 'Bar' }
}

function fooFactory(): Foo {
    return { fooProp: 'Foo' }
}

let factory: (() => Foo) | (() => Bar);

let someRuntimeValue = true;
if (someRuntimeValue) {
    factory = fooFactory;
} else {
    factory = barFactory;
}

let objects: Foo[] | Bar[];
for (let n = 0; n < 10; ++n) {
    //TS - Argument of type 'Foo | Bar' is not assignable 
    //to parameter of type 'Foo & Bar'.
    objects.push(factory()); 
}
```

Comment: `Array<Foo|Bar>`?

Comment: I want one or the other though `Foo[] | Bar[]` not `[Bar, Foo, Foo, Bar,...]`

Comment: Right, I'm not sure then, let's see if somebody comes with a suggestion.

Answer (score 0):

If it wasn't a runtime value, you could probably use templates (as long as your code was encapsulated within functions, classes, or interfaces), but because it is a variable, you'll have to use the `as any` phrase to make the compiler "ignore it" in your code like follows:

```js
let objects: Foo[] | Bar[];
for (let n = 0; n < 10; ++n) {
    objects.push(factory() as any); // ignore the `Foo | Bar` return type
}
```

In typescript, especially when doing things like this, you'll have to use the `as any` phrase quite a bit -- just make sure you are doing things correctly because the compiler *will* skip type checks here.

For instance, maybe later you want to pass it to a function which only handles the `Foo[]` type; you will have to use something similar there:

```js
function testFoo(objects: Foo[]) {
  return !objects.find(a => !(a.fooProp));
}

if(someRuntimeValue) {
  testFoo(objects as Foo[]);
}
```

Comment: Your code makes very little sense: every item of `objects` has a `Foo & Bar` type (and no type in the OPs code fulfils it). Effectively, using `as any` here is no better to declaring `objects` as `any` as well, and not using any types at all.

Comment: I'm afraid you're incorrect: every item of `objects` has a `Foo | Bar` type *if it were to follow the `factory()` return type*. In this code, `objects` still retains its type definition while we circumvent it for *only particular cases*. Because it retains its type definition (however inflexible it may be), we can retain some form of type checking later and do things as shown in the second example.

Comment: How about you check it yourself https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/#code/C4TwDgpgBAYg9nKBeKByAZg1BYAUKSKAIQEMAnZNAI3J1zwBsJgo4qArCAY2AGcAuWAgDaAXSgAfYuTGUxAbjx42nHrwB0YAK68AFgAoAjAEp5QA

Comment: "still retains its type definition" --- which as I pointed out and you will see if you click a link above - a pointless non-existing intersection type. It would have `Foo | Bar` type if you declared it as `Array<Foo | Bar>`

Comment: Correct -- the type definition is indeed very inflexible -- but it is *not* pointless. We *know* the type is either one or the other -- so, every time OP wants to do something with the `objects` variable, they will have to either determine the type (with `someRuntimeVariable`) and cast it with the `as` keyword or treat it as the inflexible intersection type; and I believe this is what they desire.

Comment: "and cast it with the as" --- I'm not sure I understand why one would use TS then :shrug: